# How to open or create a directory if doesn't exist atomically

Tags: linux, rust, directory

Is there a way to open a directory and create it if doesn't exist atomically ?

My use case is simple, I use a directory to watch every public key that are allowed to connect to my server, but if the directory doesn't exist I want to create it, unfortunately for now I only see a two step solution, create the path with [`create_dir_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html) and then open it with [`read_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.read_dir) but this create a possible situation where the directory is delete between the two calls (very unlucky in my docker container... but anyway !)

I didn't find any solution in linux to do that and I'm quite surprise cause that a very common operation for file.

I found a related question [Create a directory and return a dirfd with `open`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65168665/7076153) but it's focus on file descriptor and so is more specific. The answer seem to say this doesn't prevent race condition, I don't really understand the context, my only concern is to avoid to create the directory and than try to open it and it's fail. It's more for convenience and robustness of code.

Comment: It seems that [the POSIX `open` spec doesn't support this](https://austin-group-l.opengroup.narkive.com/9z11WMS5/atomic-mkdir-open#post2).

Comment: It's admirable that you try to protect yourself from this issue. But I can't comprehend *how unlikely* it's to time such deletion for some other program or a potential attacker. You only do it once, and since it's an initialization, then maybe crashing is a right thing to do

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov absolutely no chance for my use case I think... but... I want this anyway. But I could say the same for maybe other context I mean what are the chance someone open a file just when you create it ? still, If it's exist I would prefer to use it, it's make my code cleaner and I think it's more "natural" I create a dir give it back to me.

Comment: According to 66483396 and 66482526 there doesn't seem to be any way to protect against TOCTOU vulnerabilities for directories.

Comment: @Masklinn As I say that not my concern, I just want a better ergonomic.